# Web App execution/access scope

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

When I deploy my GAS project as a web app, I choose to execute the application as the user accessing it. The option for 'Who has access to the app' I can choose just myself, or everyone in my domain. This I understand.

However, in our Google Apps environment - the domain I belong to is one of many 'sub-domains' under one 'tld' domain to which I have an admin account. I don't have privileges to go full exploring in the control panel to see the exact organization, but I know that I can share docs to everyone in all domains via my Drive. How can I get my script to operate in a similar manner?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good resources on this topic.

1. [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063534/is-it-possible-to-have-sub-domain-email-with-google-apps) which links to this
2. [Google support answer](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182452)

With Google Drive, "You cannot restrict sharing to the users in a single domain". I haven't found an answer to this, [but this was the closest that I could find](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182081). It seems that you will just have to test if "Anyone in my domain" actually means "Anyone in my organization." If you can test this and report back, I will update this answer.